# Pinescript dynamic alert message changes value of strategy equity in tostring variable

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to create a dynamic alert message with my strategy.equity value.
I want to do this because I have 2 types of orders, and in certain conditions I want to fire an order with x units of a given asset, and other times y units.
Problem is, each time it sends the alert, the number I receive has nothing to do with the number I ploted in the same variable

```
Amount := strategy.equity/open
alert("buy" + tostring(Amount),alert.freq_all)

plot(Amount1*10000000,"1")
//Ploted times 10000000 so that I can see the value in the data window for debug
```

The ploted value I get is 91629, but the email alert shows me a number close to 42010
The variable is the same.
The value changes when sent in the alert to something that I can't understand what math is it doing.
I also tried to use the {{strategy.contracts}}, but it also sent a bit less than half of what it should in each order.
I can't understand why it is changing the alert signal.

Comment: Tried  this already: 
`alert('buy: {{plot_1}}',alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)`
And the result received was this: "Your BTCBUSD alert was triggered buy: {{plot_1}}"

Answer (score 0):

For debugging, you can see the Amount value, like this:

```
l_debug = label.new(bar_index, high, text = tostring(Amount))
label.delete(not (strategy.position_avg_price != strategy.position_avg_price[1]) ? l_debug: na)
```

Comment: The value in the debugging adds up. But then when I put the same variable in the alert() and the value I get in the email or popup alert doesn't add up is is not the same as the debug one. It's less than half.